# web3.eth.getBlock("latest") giving no object in the block!

Tags: web3js, transactions, javascript

I am trying to get the numbers of transactions in a rinkeby testnet in the last block

I wrote the following code

```
var Web3 = require('web3');

const Project_ID_Infura = 'write your own Infura ID';

const apiKey = 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/' + Project_ID_Infura;

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(apiKey));

var block = web3.eth.getBlock('latest');

console.log(Object.values(block));
```

Where as you can see it is empty! I want to get the transaction field of this `block`. How may I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there are changes when using the web3 library everytime. At the time of writing. It seems that the block variable is a promise!

What is meant by promise? Promises in JavaScript represent processes that are already happening, which can be chained with callback functions as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

So it seems that the only viable way to get how many transactions were in the last block is by adding the below line to the code above.

```
block.then(x=> {return x.transactions.length});
```

This gave me the return I want but I was unable to store it as a variable. I am still learning how to do so but thought of sharing half of the solution.

Note: A nice video explaining promise in JavaScript is available [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvYYCGs45L4)